# Build Failed in Bluemix with package not found error

Tags: ibm-cloud

Help in resolving this issue :

Started by user pipeline
    Building remotely on jenkins-build-slave-bcd9bff503a8 (.*Build) in workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff
    Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning repository https://hub.jazz.net/git/sharathsamala/WordGuess
    Fetching upstream changes from https://hub.jazz.net/git/sharathsamala/WordGuess
    using .gitcredentials to set credentials
    Checking out Revision ae1032552805c3acb45ec3693a505ad272db4356 (detached)
    First time build. Skipping changelog.
    [109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson2450631085921349728.sh
    Buildfile: /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/build.xml

```
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/bin

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/bin

build-project:
     [echo] WebStarterApp: /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/build.xml
    [javac] Compiling 8 source files to /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/bin
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:4: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:5: error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:6: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:7: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:8: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class LoadGame extends HttpServlet {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol: class HttpServlet
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @WebServlet("/LoadGame")
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class WebServlet
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
    [javac]   location: class LoadGame
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
    [javac]   location: class LoadGame
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadGame.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                                                                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ServletException
    [javac]   location: class LoadGame
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:6: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:7: error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:8: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:9: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:10: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class LoadIndex extends HttpServlet {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac]   symbol: class HttpServlet
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @WebServlet("/LoadIndex")
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class WebServlet
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
    [javac]   location: class LoadIndex
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
    [javac]   location: class LoadIndex
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/controller/LoadIndex.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                                                                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ServletException
    [javac]   location: class LoadIndex
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/data/CloudantConnection.java:7: error: package org.apache.wink.json4j does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONArray;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/data/CloudantConnection.java:8: error: package org.apache.wink.json4j does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONObject;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Category.java:3: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
    [javac] import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Category.java:4: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
    [javac] import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Category.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @JsonIgnoreProperties({"id", "revision"})
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class JsonIgnoreProperties
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Word.java:3: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
    [javac] import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Word.java:4: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
    [javac] import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Word.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @JsonIgnoreProperties({"id", "revision"})
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class JsonIgnoreProperties
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/ibm/cloudoe/samples/HelloResource.java:3: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/ibm/cloudoe/samples/HelloResource.java:4: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/ibm/cloudoe/samples/HelloResource.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @Path("/hello")
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class Path
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Category.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @JsonProperty("_id")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JsonProperty
    [javac]   location: class Category
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Category.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @JsonProperty("_rev")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JsonProperty
    [javac]   location: class Category
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Word.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @JsonProperty("_id")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JsonProperty
    [javac]   location: class Word
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/model/Word.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @JsonProperty("_rev")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JsonProperty
    [javac]   location: class Word
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/ibm/cloudoe/samples/HelloResource.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @GET
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GET
    [javac]   location: class HelloResource
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/data/CloudantConnection.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"));
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JSONObject
    [javac]   location: class CloudantConnection
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/data/CloudantConnection.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"));
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JSONObject
    [javac]   location: class CloudantConnection
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/data/CloudantConnection.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             String******** names = JSONObject.getNames(obj);
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable JSONObject
    [javac]   location: class CloudantConnection
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/data/CloudantConnection.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                         JSONArray val = obj.getJSONArray(name);
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JSONArray
    [javac]   location: class CloudantConnection
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/data/CloudantConnection.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                         JSONObject serviceAttr = val.getJSONObject(0);
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JSONObject
    [javac]   location: class CloudantConnection
    [javac] /home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/src/com/bluemix/hangman/data/CloudantConnection.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                         JSONObject credentials = serviceAttr.getJSONObject("credentials");
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JSONObject
    [javac]   location: class CloudantConnection
    [javac] 42 errors
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
/home/jenkins/workspace/ec1f37e9-e252-47eb-9f23-6285014fbac4/109c3733-91e9-432d-ba60-8cecffb912ff/build.xml:24: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing jars in your build path. Take a look at the [Java DB Web Starter](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/java-db-web-starter/) sample code. Look in the `dep-jar` and `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folders for the jar files. The jar files are then added to the buildpath in the build.xml

```
<path id="classpathDir">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/db2jcc.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/nosqljson.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="dep-jar"> 
        <include name="*.jar"/> 
    </fileset>
</path>
```

The jar files in the `dep-jar` folder are not packaged in the final war file.

Comment: sorry the above answer didn't help me ! after doing it still i'm getting the same error

Comment: you can check all the code in my get repository ie. @https://hub.jazz.net/git/sharathsamala/WordGuess

please check the code and suggest

Comment: Please fork the repository and send me the pull !

Comment: If you get a `package * not found error`, then you need to add the jar that has those packages. Because you are using open source wink and jackson packages, you need to include those jars (jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar wink-json4j-1.4.jar) in your WEB-INF/lib. This is not a Bluemix issue. If you try to compile it locally with `ant`, you will hit the same errors.